# How to implement push notifications in Intranet in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, notifications, push, mobile-application

I am trying to implement push notifications in my ionic app. 
The challenge is that the network in which the device and the backend service resides is a closed network(no internet). 
Is it possible that I get notifications somehow on my app on certain triggers from the backend?
Solutions, I've come across is, sending local notifications from my app while it continuously polls from the server.
The potential problem with this is:

1. If the app gets closed, the notifications wont show up
2. Mobile battery will be heavily drained

Is there any other fix to this or any efficient solution?
Any help is much appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible, at least for apple devices. Searching for a solution for this problem since 2014. I hope you will get an answer.

Comment: Does sending local notification works for ios? I know it does for android